# Javascript Garbage Collector in Chrome not kicking in automatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

On page load, the memory consumed by the browser increases rapidly and the browser
crashes with an **"Aw, Snap!"** message with the error code **"Out of Memory"**.

I observed that:

- If I make the **tab inactive** then the GC kicks in and collects the unreachable objects and reclaims the memory.
- The memory is also reclaimed when I **trigger a manual garbage collection** from the browser's **DevTools**.

*This indicates that there are no memory leaks and the memory is increasing
just because GC is not kicking automatically in to reclaim the memory.*

Note : This happens only in chromium based browsers[Chrome & Edge].
The page loads normally in Firefox since the memory is reclaimed regularly.

What to do in such cases? Is there any way to trigger GC from javascript?

Observation -> In chrome task manager, the Memory footprint increases rapidly, while the Javascript memory remains within limits

[image: Screenshot of chrome task manager]

Comment: issue my be with the stack, check for excessive function calls, perhaps any recursive ones

Comment: "*On page load, the memory consumed by the browser increases rapidly*" - what is your code doing?

Comment: "*Is there any way to trigger GC from javascript?*" - no, there's not.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen There are recursive functions in my code. But when I trigger the GC manually the memory gets reclaimed. Doesn't that mean that the issue is with the heap memory rather than the stack?

Comment: @Bergi I am trying to create large number of objects (mostly DOM nodes). I forgot to mention that the overall process memory increases in GBs but the javascript heap doesn't increase at such rapid rate.

Comment: It may be a bug in Chrome. You can verify it by using [bisect-builds](https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py/).